# What is a "High Energy" kill?

Tags: overwatch

When you look at your Zarya statistics under Career Profile, there is a stat called "High Energy Kills".

What are high energy kills?

Would it be, for example, kills made when your energy level is at least X%? What is X?

Comment: There's an achievement for being over 60 energy for a minute straight. I think 60 might be a better guess but not certain enough to make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly it. The number of kills made where your energy is above a certain threshold. Couldn't find the exact number. But it's probably going to be above 50 where the gun is making that satisfying buzzing sound.

Comment: I would've guessed 80 since that seems to trigger a voiceline when playing as Zarya.

Comment: I think the most important part of the question is "What is X", so this answer is a bit vacuous.